# Перемещение компаратора при перемещении std::set

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, clang

Почему эта программа выводит 1, 2, 3 в clang, gcc и msvc, соответственно? Кто прав с точки зрения стандарта? [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:20,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:20,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:20,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:20),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cmemory%3E%0A%23include+%3Cset%3E%0A%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%0Astruct+C+:+std::less%3C%3E+%7B%0A++++explicit+C(std::shared_ptr%3Cint%3E+p)+:+p(p)+%7B%7D%0A%0A++++std::shared_ptr%3Cint%3E+p%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++auto+p+%3D+std::make_shared%3Cint%3E(42)%3B%0A++++auto+s1+%3D+std::set%3Cint,+C%3E(C(p))%3B%0A%0A++++auto+s2+%3D+std::move(s1)%3B%0A++++s2+%3D+std::move(s1)%3B%0A%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+p.use_count()+%3C%3C+!%27%5Cn!%27%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%271%27,compiler:clang1600,compilerName:%27%27,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-stdlib%3Dlibc%2B%2B%27,overrides:!(),source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+clang+16.0.0+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%271%27,compiler:g131,compilerName:%27%27,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27%27,overrides:!(),source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+gcc+13.1+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <set>
#include <utility>

struct C : std::less<> {
    explicit C(std::shared_ptr<int> p) : p(p) {}

    std::shared_ptr<int> p;
};

int main() {
    auto p = std::make_shared<int>(42);
    auto s1 = std::set<int, C>(C(p));

    auto s2 = std::move(s1);
    s2 = std::move(s1);

    std::cout << p.use_count() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Код не рабочий. Ещё было бы хорошо сразу ссылок на godbolt какой-нибудь.

Comment: Думаю в стандарте нет ни слова о том, должен ли быть компаратор разделяемым ли нет, и потому копиляторы делают что хотят. Разные реализации `std` же.

Comment: Код взят из https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2023/05/10/lwg-2227/. Вам недостаточно объяснения из статьи?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/sh6338xEo

Comment: Мне кажется хорошим тоном было бы упоминать в таких случаях источник в вопросе.

Comment: Я по сути ничего не поменял, довил побольше логов (наблюдаемого поведения), и вывод совпал у Clang и GCC. Выше ссылка

Comment: Стандарт не детализирует в каком состоянии должен оставаться s1 после  `s2 = std::move(s1)`. Все правы.